# open sublime with custom url scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, url-scheme

The rails gem better provides a nice interface to debug rails web applications. Clicking on file names should open your preferred text editor e.g. TextMate. With Sublime however, nothing happens.

How is it possible to register a url scheme handler for subl:// ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem. After some searching I found the [subl-handler](https://github.com/asuth/subl-handler) on github.

You need to setup your sublime so you can use the subl-command in your terminal. Look for this [guide](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).

Installing solved the problem.